# identification: strange parts in a sprue

Tags: part-identification, clone-brands

Found this in my random parts bag.

[image]

No Lego logo's anywhere, also the shade of blue is slightly off the standard blue in the Lego colour palette. The bottoms do seem to fit quite snug on Lego studs...
I do not recall how I obtained this.
Can anyone identify this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is part # [6923 : Scala Accessories - Complete Sprue - Perfume Bottles (Belville)](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=6932#T=C)

in Blue it appears in :
[Set # 3849: Orient Bazaar](https://brickset.com/sets/3849-1/Orient-Bazaar)

[image]

[image: Orient Bazaar]

Comment: Seeing the other contents of that set, I recall how I obtained the parts. I ordered a number of the coins (gold coloured 2x2 round tiles) in this set through bricklink, the seller gifted me the part as an extra